# How to query after a starsystem that cointains two planets with a mass higer than 10 times a standard mass

Tags: postgresql, join, subquery

I am working on a task in order to learn PostgreSQL, and got stuck on a problem.

Given the two tables: a `star`-table and a `planet`-table. The `star`-table contains star systems, and the `planet`-table contains planets that are located within the star systems. In other words the `planet`-table references the `star`-table with the foreign key `star`.

**My question is:** How do you query for a planet name that is contained in a solar system with **two planets** **with a mass greater than 10** standard masses, where the star has a distance less than 50 parsecs away from our sun? (The standard mass measurement in this specific task is a scale of Jupiter masses referenced as a whole number).

**the tables look like this:**

[image]

**My best previous attempt goes likes this, and return 79 rows.**

```
SELECT p.name, s.name FROM planet AS p
  INNER JOIN star AS s
      ON (s.name = p.star)
  WHERE s.distance < 50 AND p.mass > 10;   -- I don't know how to check for two planets with a mass greater than 10
```

The correct answer should return 4 rows.

All help is appreciated and much welcomed

Comment: how about adding aggregate functions, COUNT. and a HAVING statement.

Like select count(*), p.name, s.name FROM planet .....

where .... having count(*) > 2

Answer (score 1):

Your query will do, but since you only want to query for the star system, the following may be closer to what you want:

```
SELECT s.name
FROM star AS s
WHERE s.distance < 50
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM planet AS p
              WHERE s.name = p.star
                AND p.mass > 10);
```